# Открытие картинок и видео в JPanel Java Swing

Tags: java, swing, изображения, видео, jpanel

Есть одно, родительское, окно - `JFrame`. В нём есть `JPanel`. 
Как мне выводить картинку и воспроизводить видео в этом `JPanel`?
Может есть какая-то библиотека?

Особенность в том что перед воспроизведением или показом нужно убрать из `JPanel` то что сейчас. Тобишь если сейчас картинка то она убирается и в нём воспроизводится видео, и так далее.

Спасибо.

Comment: Посмотрите в каком сейчас состоянии gstreamer вообще и для java в частности. Есть ещё библиотека для DirectShow. А убирать или прятать компоненты - это же элементарно.

Comment: @Sergey а примеры есть?

Comment: Там есть примеры. У меня не осталось.